# Online list of water of crystallisation?

Tags: cheminformatics, databases

I was extremely happy to recently receive a copy of the Nuffield Revised Book of Data but was somewhat disappointed to find that it did not list data on the water of crystallisation for various compounds.

Does anybody know of any large online tables or databases of reliable water-of-crystallisation data?

Comment: Do you mean a list of compounds like $\ce{CaSO4.2H_2O, CaSO4.1/2H2O}$, etc. ?

Comment: Yeah, and perhaps the conditions under which they form? Ideally with excess water.

Comment: You can find some data in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_of_crystallization).

Comment: It's literally just a list of at most 20 compounds, which is hardly comprehensive nor does it list the conditions under which they are formed given that the same compound can form different hydrates under varying amounts of water.

Comment: What would be the scientific value of such a list? If you can answer that, it might lead to a place where it could be found, or an author who has compiled it.